Why i'm getting an object after sanitizing a string in angular?
Hi i'm getting this strange error in my app:
ERROR RuntimeError: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '%5Bobject%20Object%5D'
    at Recognizer.noMatchError (d:/TRABAJO/FINAL/front/node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs:3705:12)
    at eval (d:/TRABAJO/FINAL/front/node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs:3738:20)
    at eval (d:/TRABAJO/FINAL/front/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/operators/catchError.js:10:39)
    at OperatorSubscriber.OperatorSubscriber._error (d:/TRABAJO/FINAL/front/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/operators/OperatorSubscriber.js:23:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (d:/TRABAJO/FINAL/front/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/Subscriber.js:40:18)
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (d:/TRABAJO/FINAL/front/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/Subscriber.js:64:30)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (d:/TRABAJO/FINAL/front/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/Subscriber.js:40:18)
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (d:/TRABAJO/FINAL/front/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/Subscriber.js:64:30)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (d:/TRABAJO/FINAL/front/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/Subscriber.js:40:18)
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (d:/TRABAJO/FINAL/front/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/Subscriber.js:64:30) {
  code: 4002
}

I'm using bootstrap carousel to show some pictures from my backend, but this comes with 2 files one for phones and other to devices with large width so my component is like this:
constructor(private photosService: PhotosService, private petitionsService: PetitionsService) {

      this.loading = true;
      this.getCarrusel()
      afterRender(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
        this.resizeSubscription = fromEvent(window, 'resize').subscribe(() => {
          if (window.innerWidth < 749) {
            this.imgResponsive = true
          } else {
            this.imgResponsive = false
          }
        });

        if (window.innerWidth < 749) {
          this.imgResponsive = true
        } else {
          this.imgResponsive = false
        }

      })
  }

And my service is like this:
getCarrusel() {
    this.photosService.getCarrusel().subscribe((data) => {
      data.forEach((element: Carrusel) => {
        element.file = this.petitionsService.sanitizar(element.file)
        element.fileResponsive = this.petitionsService.sanitizar(element.fileResponsive)
      })
      this.slides = data;
    })
  }

As you can see I'm also sanitizing my images and i'm using this function:
sanitizar(cadena) {
    if (cadena) {
      cadena = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(cadena);
      return cadena
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

So now what, all seems ok but The error source is this:
<img _ngcontent-ng-c2054693178="" alt="..." class="d-block w-100" src="[object Object]">

this is a copy paste from the browser console, why is generating an object in the src? all my variables are string because the image is coming like this from the api: "data:image/*;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgA..."
And this error is only in this path, if I change the page and return to this, works perfectly, is so strange. And is not only in this petition, in this component I get some other content and also the image fail with this same error
I'm using angular 17 with SSR.
So I asume sanitizer have something to do with it and yeah! if I don't use the function in any function that function work, so I don't know why, this is the way angular tells you to sanitize images so I'm realy lost

please refine your question with the minimal reproducible code, there is a routing error, but there is nothing present about routing, should the image error be another question?

DomSanitizer returns a SafeHtml object, which indicates to angular the html inside can be trusted and wasn't injected by the user
